# How do I Remove Specific Characters From File Names Using BASH

Tags: bash

I have a lot of files that have a shared pattern in their name that I would like to remove.  For example I have the files, "a_file000.tga" and "another_file000.tga".  I would like to do an operation on those files that would remove the pattern "000" from their names resulting in the new names, "a_file.tga" and "another_file.tga".

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Try this (this works in plain old Bourne `sh` as well):

```
for i in *000.tga
do
    mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed 's/000//'`"
done
```

Both arguments are wrapped in quotes to support spaces in the filenames.

Comment: +1 for most portable solution (and because I'm running too low on upvotes to keep upvoting _all_ the good answers).

Comment: Portable, but slow and buggy (`echo $i` is itself buggy for the reasons described in [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else), and running a separate copy of `sed` for each name is _very_ slow)

Comment: ...also, backticks are bad form -- `$( )` has been standardized as part of the POSIX sh standard (which supersedes 1970s Bourne) since the early 1990s; there's no good reason to keep using the old form that's hard to nest and changes the meaning of backslashes within them.

Answer (score 105):

Bash can do `sed`-like substitutions:

```
for file in *; do mv "${file}" "${file/000/}"; done
```

Comment: Works nicely on OS X (10.6.8). Handy and succinct. Thanks.

Comment: Nice, can you explain the function of  "{" ?

Comment: @efrem: The curly braces are an optional delimiter for variable names and are necessary for parameter expansions. See the [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for more information.

Comment: For documentation on this functionality please see section 3.5.3 [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) from _Bash Reference Manual_, look for `${parameter/pattern/string}`.

More detailed examples of parameter substitution could be found in section 10.2 [Parameter Substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) from _Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide_.

Comment: @irnc: Another: [Parameter Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters?#Parameter_Expansion)

Comment: Best answer, IMO.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks

Comment: `for file in *; do mv "${file}" "${file/\n/}"; done`
I can not delete the newline character. I tested that other characters are OK.

Comment: @hrdom: You will need to use special quoting in order to have the newline escape interpreted: `for file in *; do mv "${file}" "${file/$'\n/'}"; done` . And if your filenames might have more than one newline and you want to remove all of them then double the first slash: `for file in *; do mv "${file}" "${file//$'\n/'}"; done`

Answer (score 13):

A non-bash solution, since I know two speedy posters have already covered that:

There's an excellent short perl program called `rename` which is installed by default on some systems (others have a less useful rename program). It lets you use perl regex for your renaming, e.g:

```
rename 's/000//' *000*.tga
```

Answer (score 4):

Use rename, maybe you need to install it on linux, Its python script

```
rename (option) 's/oldname/newname' ...
```

so you can use it like

```
rename -v 's/000//' *.tga
```

that means we are instructing to replace all files with .tga extension in that folder to replace `000` with empty space. Hope that works

You can check [this](https://www.maketecheasier.com/rename-files-in-linux/) link for more info and [here](https://www.tecmint.com/rename-multiple-files-in-linux/)

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash
ls | while read name; do
  echo mv $name ${name/$1//}
done
```

Comment: @Laurence Gonsalves: using shell wildcards expand the command line, and there's a not-so big limit there.  "while read" avoids that

Comment: @Laurence: This is also much more extensible. It's commonly used with `find` on the front.

Comment: `while read` is an improvement (if it were used correctly, with an empty `IFS` and `-r`, and `-d ''` and a NUL-delimited input stream), but `ls` is the opposite. See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)