# I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else

Tags: bash, shell, sh, quoting

Here are a series of cases where `echo $var` can show a different value than what was just assigned. This happens regardless of whether the assigned value was "double quoted", 'single quoted' or unquoted.

How do I get the shell to set my variable correctly?

**Asterisks**

The expected output is `/* Foobar is free software */`, but instead I get a list of filenames:

```
$ var="/* Foobar is free software */"
$ echo $var 
/bin /boot /dev /etc /home /initrd.img /lib /lib64 /media /mnt /opt /proc ...
```

**Square brackets**

The expected value is `[a-z]`, but sometimes I get a single letter instead!

```
$ var=[a-z]
$ echo $var
c
```

**Line feeds (newlines)**

The expected value is a  a list of separate lines, but instead all the values are on one line!

```
$ cat file
foo
bar
baz

$ var=$(cat file)
$ echo $var
foo bar baz
```

**Multiple spaces**

I expected a carefully aligned table header, but instead multiple spaces either disappear or are collapsed into one!

```
$ var="       title     |    count"
$ echo $var
title | count
```

**Tabs**

I expected two tab separated values, but instead I get two space separated values!

```
$ var=$'key\tvalue'
$ echo $var
key value
```

Comment: Thanks for doing this. I encounter the line feeds one often. So `var=$(cat file)` is fine, but `echo "$var"` is needed.

Comment: BTW, this is also BashPitfalls #14: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable

Comment: Also, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414150/how-do-i-preserve-newlines-in-a-quoted-string-in-bash

Answer (score 206, accepted):

In all of the cases above, the variable is correctly set, but not correctly read! The right way is to **use double quotes *when referencing***:

```
echo "$var"
```

This gives the expected value in all the examples given. Always quote variable references!

---

Why?

When a variable is **unquoted**, it will:

1. Undergo [field splitting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_05) where the value is split into multiple words on whitespace (by default):

   Before: `/* Foobar is free software */`

   After: `/*`, `Foobar`, `is`, `free`, `software`, `*/`
2. Each of these words will undergo [pathname expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_06), where patterns are expanded into matching files:

   Before: `/*`

   After: `/bin`, `/boot`, `/dev`, `/etc`, `/home`, ...
3. Finally, all the arguments are passed to echo, which writes them out [separated by single spaces](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html#tag_20_37_10), giving

   ```
   /bin /boot /dev /etc /home Foobar is free software Desktop/ Downloads/
   ```

   instead of the variable's value.

When the variable is **quoted** it will:

1. Be substituted for its value.
2. There is no step 2.

This is why you should **always quote all variable references**, unless you specifically require word splitting and pathname expansion. Tools like [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) are there to help, and will warn about missing quotes in all the cases above.

Comment: it's not always working. I can give an example: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8RjR6CS668/

Comment: Yup, `$(..)` strips trailing linefeeds. You can use `var=$(cat file; printf x); var="${var%x}"` to work around it.

Answer (score 27):

You may want to know why this is happening. Together with [the great explanation by that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29378567/1983854), find a reference of [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/40596) written by [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) in [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/):

> ### Why do I need to write `"$foo"`? What happens without the quotes?
>
> `$foo` does not mean “take the value of the variable `foo`”. It means
>   something much more complex:
>
> - First, take the value of the variable.
> - Field splitting: treat that value as a whitespace-separated list of fields, and build the resulting list. For example, if the variable
>     contains `foo *  bar ​` then the result of this step is the 3-element
>     list `foo`, `*`, `bar`.
> - Filename generation: treat each field as a glob, i.e. as a wildcard pattern, and replace it by the list of file names that match this
>     pattern. If the pattern doesn't match any files, it is left
>     unmodified. In our example, this results in the list containing `foo`,
>     following by the list of files in the current directory, and finally
>     `bar`. If the current directory is empty, the result is `foo`, `*`,
>     `bar`.
>
> Note that the result is a list of strings. There are two contexts in
>   shell syntax: list context and string context. Field splitting and
>   filename generation only happen in list context, but that's most of
>   the time. Double quotes delimit a string context: the whole
>   double-quoted string is a single string, not to be split. (Exception:
>   `"$@"` to expand to the list of positional parameters, e.g. `"$@"` is
>   equivalent to `"$1" "$2" "$3"` if there are three positional
>   parameters. See [What is the difference between $* and $@?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41571/what-is-the-difference-between-and/94200#94200))
>
> The same happens to command substitution with `$(foo)` or with 
>   `` `foo` ``. On a side note, don't use `` `foo` ``: its quoting rules are
>   weird and non-portable, and all modern shells support `$(foo)` which
>   is absolutely equivalent except for having intuitive quoting rules.
>
> The output of arithmetic substitution also undergoes the same
>   expansions, but that isn't normally a concern as it only contains
>   non-expandable characters (assuming `IFS` doesn't contain digits or
>   `-`).
>
> See [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary) for more details about the
>   cases when you can leave out the quotes.
>
> Unless you mean for all this rigmarole to happen, just remember to
>   always use double quotes around variable and command substitutions. Do
>   take care: leaving out the quotes can lead not just to errors but to
>   [security
>   holes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells/171347#171347).

Answer (score 14):

In addition to other issues caused by failing to quote, `-n` and `-e` can be consumed by `echo` as arguments. (Only the former is legal per the POSIX spec for `echo`, but several common implementations violate the spec and consume `-e` as well).

To avoid this, **use `printf` instead of `echo` when details matter.**

Thus:

```
$ vars="-e -n -a"
$ echo $vars      # breaks because -e and -n can be treated as arguments to echo
-a
$ echo "$vars"
-e -n -a
```

However, correct quoting won't always save you when using `echo`:

```
$ vars="-n"
$ echo "$vars"
$ ## not even an empty line was printed
```

...whereas it **will** save you with `printf`:

```
$ vars="-n"
$ printf '%s\n' "$vars"
-n
```

Comment: Yay, we need a good dedup for this! I agree this fits the question title, but I don't think it'll get the visibility it deserves here. How about a new question à la "Why is my `-e`/`-n`/backslash not showing up?"  We can add links from here as appropriate.

Comment: Did you mean *consume `-n` as well*?

Comment: @PesaThe, no, I meant `-e`. The standard for `echo` does not specify output when its first argument is `-n`, making any/all possible output legal in that case; there is no such provision for `-e`.

Answer (score 13):

user double quote to get the exact value. like this:

```
echo "${var}"
```

and it will read your value correctly.

Comment: root@ubuntu:/home/qgb# var_a=100 echo ${var_a}

Answer (score 3):

`echo $var` output highly depends on the value of `IFS` variable. By default it contains space, tab, and newline characters:

```
[ks@localhost ~]$ echo -n "$IFS" | cat -vte
 ^I$
```

This means that when shell is doing field splitting (or word splitting) it uses all these characters as word separators. This is what happens when referencing a variable without double quotes to echo it (`$var`) and thus expected output is altered.

One way to prevent word splitting (besides using double quotes) is to set `IFS` to null. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_05 :

> If the value of IFS is null, no field splitting shall be performed.

Setting to null means setting to empty 
value:

```
IFS=
```

---

Test:

```
[ks@localhost ~]$ echo -n "$IFS" | cat -vte
 ^I$
[ks@localhost ~]$ var=$'key\nvalue'
[ks@localhost ~]$ echo $var
key value
[ks@localhost ~]$ IFS=
[ks@localhost ~]$ echo $var
key
value
[ks@localhost ~]$
```

Comment: You would also have to `set -f` to prevent globbing

Comment: @thatotherguy, is it really necessary for your 1-st example with path expansion? With `IFS` set to null, `echo $var` will be expanded to `echo '/* Foobar is free software */'` and path expansion is not performed inside single quoted strings.

Comment: Yes. If you `mkdir "/this thing called Foobar is free software etc/"` you'll see that it still expands. It's obviously more practical for the `[a-z]` example.

Comment: I see, this makes sense for `[a-z]` example.

Comment: ```root@ubuntu:/home/qgb# var=32321 echo $var

root@ubuntu:/home/qgb# var=3231; echo $var
3231```

Answer (score 2):

The [answer from ks1322](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else/33719549#33719549) helped me to identify the issue while using `docker-compose exec`:

If you omit the `-T` flag, `docker-compose exec` add a special character that break output, we see `b` instead of `1b`:

```
$ test=$(/usr/local/bin/docker-compose exec db bash -c "echo 1")
$ echo "${test}b"
b
```

```
echo "${test}" | cat -vte
1^M$
```

With `-T` flag, `docker-compose exec` works as expected:

```
$ test=$(/usr/local/bin/docker-compose exec -T db bash -c "echo 1")
$ echo "${test}b"
1b
```

Answer (score -1):

Additional to putting the variable in quotation, one could also translate the output of the variable using `tr` and converting spaces to newlines.

```
$ echo $var | tr " " "\n"
foo
bar
baz
```

Although this is a little more convoluted, it does add more diversity with the output as you can substitute any character as the separator between array variables.

Comment: But this substitutes *all* spaces to newlines. Quoting preserves the existing newlines and spaces.

Comment: True, yes. I suppose it depends on what is within the variable. I actually use `tr` the other way around to create arrays from text files.

Comment: Creating a problem by not quoting the variable properly and then working around it with a hamfisted extra process is not good programming.

Comment: @Alek, ...err, what? There's no `tr` needed to properly/correctly create an array from a text file -- you can specify whatever separator you want by setting IFS. For instance: `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a arrayname < <(cat file.txt && printf '\0')` works all the way back through bash 3.2 (the oldest version in wide circulation), and correctly sets exit status to false if your `cat` failed. And if you wanted, say, tabs instead newlines, you'd just replace the `$'\n'` with `$'\t'`.

Comment: @Alek, ...if you're doing something like `arrayname=( $( cat file | tr '\n' ' ' ) )`, then that's broken on multiple layers: It's globbing your results (so a `*` turns into a list of files in the current directory), and *it would work just as well without the `tr`* (or the `cat`, for that matter; one could just use `arrayname=$( $(<file) )` and it would be broken in the same ways, but less inefficiently so).